# Javascript client framework with Rails JSON API - how to do integration tests?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, javascript-framework

I have two applications, a Rails JSON API, and a Javascript client framework.

What is the best way to do integration tests ?

And another question, can this be done via Capybara ?

Comment: Check this: http://tom-clements.com/blog/2012/02/25/capybara-on-the-command-line-live-browser-testing-from-irb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a true integration test, you can use Capybara with a driver that executes javascript, like [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist), or [Capybara-Webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit). Alternatively, you could use Selenium, but that's not quite as slick as a headless test.

That said, you will probably have a lot more luck and more solid tests if you test your front end and back end separately with Rspec on the back and Jasmine/Qunit on the front. Integration tests with JS are often tricky.